# Common symbols for a variant of a transformation

Tags: notation

There is an already known transformation $X$. I want to define a variation of it that happens to be more general than $X$. Not fully general, but it is more than the original $X$.

What are common accents, symbols or notation normally used to convey this idea? (I am thinking on some star, hat, apostrophe...
$X^*$, $X'$, $\hat{X}$, $X_{g}$, etc.). In computer science the star usually means "the optimal", so I am not sure if it is good idea to use that one.

I am not a mathematician, so please excuse me if I am using the wrong terminology here.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: More general, *how*? If it is a natural generalization to a broader domain (or has an extra input to distinguish it), then it might not cause confusion to keep the same symbol $X$. The best conventions to use/avoid vary depending on subfield, too, so more context would help on that front as well. For instance, maybe $\hat X$ is great or maybe it's terrible in your subfield because it conflicts with notation for the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of $X$ and the context makes that a reasonable point of confusion.

Comment: I see. The transformation denotes an algorithm that performs a permutation in a 1D array of integers. The input of the general case is the same as in $X$, but the original $X$ needs to find $2^i$ elements, and makes the permutation element-wise. This generalization does not need $2^i$ elements in the input, and makes the permutation on groups of 1 or more elements.

Comment: Is anything similar done in related papers? I don't quite understand your comment, but my instinct is still the same: "just say 'we can extend $X$ to numbers of elements that are not powers of two in the following way:...' and then keep using $X$".

Comment: I'm not aware of a similar thing done in other papers. I see what you mean, just stating the generalization but keep using X.